# Why does my LED light-fixture in my kitchen flicker for a few minutes after being turned on

Tags: light-fixture, kitchens, led

I have an LED kitchen light that is a few years old (Lowes). When I turn it on it flickers for about 30 seconds and then gives regular light. If the light is turned off, and then back on, it does not flicker.

Comment: Can you give a better description of the light.  Make and model?  does it use LED bulbs or is it a florescent replacement?   Are the leds integrated?  Is it on a circuit with other lights?  More info please.